# Filter LINQ from CheckBox checked values in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a form which will have three checkboxes, say:

```
@Html.CheckBox("Active", true)
@Html.CheckBox("Closed", false)
@Html.CheckBox("Finalized", false)
```

...and a controller mapped to these default values (maybe that's not the best way)

```
public ActionResult TempView(bool Active = false, bool Closed = false, bool Finalized = false)
    { .... }
```

...and then a button to apply the filter to cause some AJAX magic and select from the table where some property is in the checked values from the filter.

I've got nowhere, besides a bunch of `If Active is checked, WHERE Property = Active, Or If Closed is checked, WHERE Property = Closed [...]`

Is there an easy implementation in LINQ to do this with a number of Boolean values?  The user could select all three boxes at the same time (not just one or the other)

Comment: Use radio buttons, not checkboxes.  Checkboxes are semantically incorrect for your particular scenario.

Comment: How is that?  Radio buttons would assume only one value is selected; however, the user could check all three (Active, Closed, Finalized) at the same time

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't know that.  Well, each checkbox is its own boolean field in your data model (table).  Does that help?  Otherwise, it's going to be bitmask flags in your `Property`, which will be a mess.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that, either.  This is all one field, "State."  To put it in (sort of) SQL terms, `WHERE State IN (selected values)`

Comment: Didn't you just tell me you could have more than one checkbox checked?  How are you going to store three discrete values in the same database field?

Comment: Yes... So, the user checks Active and Closed.  WHERE State = Active or State = Closed

Comment: `WHERE ACTIVE=TRUE OR CLOSED=TRUE`  You need separate fields in your database for each check box.

Comment: Active isn't it's own property, it's not saying that this row is an active row, it's a state of some project.  Imagine we are working with colors... I want to see anything that is Blue or anything that is Green.  Where Color = Blue or Color = Green.  Active and State are not two different properties.  Active and Closed are both States

Comment: But you can't have blue and green at the same time.  It's either blue or it's green.  So here are your choices.  You can either 1.  Have radio buttons that track a single state, and store that state in a single field in your database, or 2. Have check boxes for each individual state, and a field in your table for each individual check box.  The fields would be ACTIVE, CLOSED, and FINALIZED.  They would each be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: I think a bit more code is in order, regarding what you've tried, especially expanding on the phrase "besides a bunch of...", since it might help us figure out what SQL or LINQ you'd like as the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve, I created a new type, `SummaryFilterInfo`, which looks like this:

```
public class SummaryFilterInfo
{
    public List<State> States { get; set; }
    public List<State> StateSelection { get; set; }

    public SummaryFilterInfo()
    {
        var stateList = new StateList();
        States = new List<State>();
        StateSelection = stateList.GetAllStates();
    }
}
```

I then use `StateSelection` to populate an array of CheckBoxes, with names like:

```
SummaryFilterInfo_States[0]
```

And my Controller definition looks like:

```
public ActionResult Index(SummaryFilterInfo summaryFilterInfo)
    {
        ...
        var filtered = all
                       .Where(e => summaryFilterInfo.States.Contains(e.State)).ToList()
    }
```